# Firebase: Get reference to first item/element

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get a reference to the fist item in a firebase "Array"

In my case it would be `"ElmmycgjS1Nvq.../albums/-IrdMMds"`

[image]

But I'm not sure how to contsturct the query:

```
dbRef.child("ElmmycgjS.../albums").???.child("name"); // = "Brothers in Arms"
```

Where `???` should be something like `getFirst()`.
Suppose I don't know the `Id` of the first Album beforehand (`-IrdMMds`). I just need to get the first one. I've tried `limitToFirst(1).getRef()` but this didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a query that listens for the first child:

```
Query first = dbRef.child("ElmmycgjS.../albums").limitToFirst(1);
```

And then attach a listener to that query.

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the result of the query will be a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the it will be a list of one result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm trying to get a reference to the name of the album itself, not just the first item. In my case it would be "Brothers in arms". To give you a little bit of context, I'm injecting a DatabaseReference using dagger that has to point to exactly that node on the db. (The question is dumbed down a little, in reality "name" is actually a list of things, that I have to display on the activity being injected).

Comment: Please add the [minimal, complete information to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now it seems to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), one that is still not clear to me. If you want to query to find the album containing a specific song, then say that.

Comment: "If you want to query to find the album containing a specific song, then say that":

It's right there in my question.
--->
I'm not sure how to contsturct the query:
dbRef.child("ElmmycgjS.../albums").???.child("name"); // = "Brothers in Arms".

-- And It's also specified in my previous comment, sorry if I was not clear enough.

Comment: The question can be summarised to "how to get a reference to the node 'name' ". You answer is useful, but it gives me a reference to the parent node "-IrdMMdS"